# rand() only returns 1 as an answer

Tags: php, css

I was trying to randomly switch between 10 animations using a combination of php and css using this code. It everything works except that the rand() always comes out as "1" no matter how many times I reload the page or open and close the tab. What am I doing wrong?

```
<style type="text/css">
#a {width:200; height:200; background-color:black; color:red; font-size:30; position:relative; left:50; top:50;
<?php
$z=mt_rand(1,10);
if ($z="1")
{echo "animation:a 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:a 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:a 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:a 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="2")
{echo "animation:b 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:b 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:b 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:b 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="3")
{echo "animation:c 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:c 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:c 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:c 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="4")
{echo "animation:d 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:d 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:d 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:d 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="5")
{echo "animation:e 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:e 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:e 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:e 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="6")
{echo "animation:f 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:f 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:f 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:f 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="7")
{echo "animation:g 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:g 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:g 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:g 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="8")
{echo "animation:h 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:h 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:h 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:h 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="9")
{echo "animation:i 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:i 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:i 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:i 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
elseif($z="10")
{echo "animation:j 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -webkit-animation:j 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -mox-animation:j 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; -o-animation:j 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";}
?>
}
</style>
```

Comment: change all `=` to `==` and why do you use double quotes around numbers?

Comment: "why do you use double quotes round numbers?" - I am curious about that too.

Answer (score 5):

Your `if` clause uses assignment `=` instead of `==`.

Plus, I guess your `$z` is an integer, right? No need to quote it with double quotes.

```
if($z === 1) {
  // ...
} elseif($z === 2) {
  // ...
}
```

**Side Note:** `===` checks its data type as well.

Also, for so many if else cases, suggest to use `switch` case instead.

```
switch($z) {
  case 1:
    // ...
    break;
  case 2:
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd simplify all this and avoid code repeating.

```
<?php
    $letter = chr(ord("a") + mt_rand(0, 9));
    echo "animation:".$letter." 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; ";
    echo "-webkit-animation:".$letter." 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; ";
    echo "-mox-animation:".$letter." 5s linear 1s infinite alternate; ";
    echo "-o-animation:".$letter." 5s linear 1s infinite alternate;";
```